# Spring REST MongoDB Starter Application queries

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, spring-rest

So I used the Spring MongoDB application starter kit from Github. I tried running the application and it ran great. All the functionality work great. I am confused how the connection for this is being established. Where does one specify the db userid, password and the db name? Coming from a MySQL background, though MongoDB isnt a mountain there are some differences that dont set clearly in the mind of newbies.

I followed the official documentation from here : https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/. Maybe can the above info be added to the docs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read some docs on Springboot. Springboot is opinionated.  That means it assumes lot of stuff and sets-up lot of things for you. For example, in your case, As soon as it sees mongo dependency in your pom. It will create a connection to mongodb with default values which are as follows

```
host: localhost  
port: 27017  
username:  
password:  
database: test
```

That is how it is working. But if you want it to be customized, even that is made easy by specifying in configuration files (application.properties or yaml). See the list of configuration properties that you can set
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Comment: I dont have a application.properties or any yaml file. Do we need to create this file manually?

Comment: yes, you need to. You can place it under `src/main/resources` folder to be picked up by springboot by default.